# Show that $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$ are not conformally eqivalent.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> Show that $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$ are not conformally eqivalent.

my argument is that if they are ,then let $f$ is the conformal map.then f have removable singularity at $0$ since $f(z)$ is bounded.that mean f is entire and hence constant map ,which is contradiction since $f$ is injective.

is this corrrect ??
or any other suggestion

Comment: Yes, your method is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right.I think It not exist A continuous map connecte C╲{0} and D╲{0},just not topology eqivalent.you can get this by addtion one point compactness or calculate their fundamental group.